# What does 晓敏 means

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand 晓敏 is girls name. Understood. but what exactly that means?

晓 dawn, to know

敏 quick, clever, smart

Is it quick dawn? Know quickness?  Quick ? Clever? Smart Dawn? Smart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first-names, sometimes two characters join together and form a simple meaning   e.g. 国強 could mean '国家富强  (the nation is strong)'  or  '国之強者 (the strong one in the nation)'

晓 and 敏 is not this kind of name, each character contains multiple meanings and it is free to personal interpretations

- 晓 (dawn; daybreak; tell; explain; understand)
- 敏 (nimble; agile; quick; intelligent; clever; smart; preceptive)

The name 晓敏 contains all the meanings above. You can interpret it as 'hopeful (dawn represents hope) and preceptive' or 'clever and have a bright future (daybreak is just the beginning of a bright day)'

The interpretation has to be within logic, I don't think to interpret 晓敏 as 'understand nimble' is reasonable

Answer (score 1):

I am from China and just pass the CET-4 test. The following content is from machine translation, I made some modifications. If you encounter problems, please try to view the attached Chinese original text.

"晓敏" is just a common name, and it doesn't have much meaning. You can understand the meaning of each word individually, but putting them together has no meaning.

“晓” is an uncommon surname, relatively remote, and even most folklore scholars have not been able to understand its origin. Only the 《续通志·氏族略》 contains: “初见于《姓苑》，来源未详……”.

“敏” is a very common name. There are many people called “张敏” around me, both male and female. It has nothing to do with the last name.

Don't think too much, it just a common name.

---

“晓敏”只是一个普通的名字，并没有太多的含义，你可以单独理解每个字的含义，但是把它们放在一起没有任何意义。

晓是一个不太常见的姓，较为偏僻，甚至多数民俗学者至今无法了解到它的来源，仅《续通志·氏族略》里有收载：“初见于《姓苑》，来源未详……”。

敏是一个很常见的名，在我身边就有很多叫做“张敏”的人，有男有女。它与姓并没有太多关系。

不要想太多，它只是一个普通的名字而已。

Comment: Yes. Sometimes names were given not for its meaning but due to the particular birth date of the person, and the radical components of the word, like having, say, "water", "fire", "earth", "metal", are used to "balance-up" the person's astrological reading.